# how to show dash linebelow text view

Tags: android, android-layout

this is my code below which show dash line on center of textview i want to show below the textview like this:

[image: textview with dashed lines]

How can I change this to show below the textview dash line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <TextView

       android:id="@+id/apprentTemp"
       android:textColor="#000000"
       android:background="@drawable/dotted"
       android:paddingLeft="10dp"
       android:gravity="left"/>

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/localTime"
      android:textColor="#000000"
      android:background="@drawable/dotted"
      android:gravity="center"/>

</TableRow>

       <----   dashed.xml   -->

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:shape="line">

   <stroke
       android:color="#000000"
       android:dashWidth="5px"
       android:dashGap="5px" />

</shape>
```

Comment: add a border/ stroke to your textview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use

```
android:drawableBottom="@drawable/dotted"
```

instead

```
android:background="@drawable/dotted"
```

**EDIT:**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:left="-5dp"
    android:right="-5dp"
    android:top="-5dp">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:dashGap="5dp"
            android:dashWidth="5dp"
            android:color="@android:color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: How... I have everything working perfectly... Ok, I'll check it one more

Comment: i just add   <solid android:color="#ffffff" />  in ur code now is work now thank you so much

Comment: it works when i use android:background="@drawable/dotted" .. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try this

***dashed.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line" >

    <stroke
        android:dashGap="2dip"
        android:dashWidth="2dip"
        android:color="@android:color/black" />

    <size android:width="60dp"
          android:height="6dp"/>

</shape>
```

**then use**

```
android:drawableBottom="@drawable/dashed"
```

in your `TextView`

**instead of**

`android:background="@drawable/dotted"`

**Output:**

[image: Line_below_textview]

Comment: I have updated my post with corrected dashed.xml file. I tested it as well, working for me. Actually the <size> was missing in the xml.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it.Little modifications and worked.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
  >
    <shape
        android:shape="line">
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:dashGap="0dp"
            android:dashWidth="5dp"
            android:color="@color/statusLight" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

[image]

---

Just add android:dashGap to whatever value you desire.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the dashed line in the center of the view then use the below code.  like -------- Or continue with ----------

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:left="-5dp"
    android:right="-5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <shape
        android:shape="line">
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:dashGap="2dp"
            android:dashWidth="5dp"
            android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
  <TextView
 android:id="@+id/total"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="right"
 android:text="TextView" 
 android:drawableBottom="@drawable/dividerline"/>
```

Make one xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <size
        android:height="1dp"
        android:width="70dp" />

    <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />

</shape>
```